# Get the stomp client used internally by Spring Broker Relay

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-websocket, stomp

I'm trying to setup a broker relay in Spring with RabbitMQ being the broker. Things work as intended when all events originate from my browser, however, sometimes I have events generated on the server side dynamically. I want to send these too to RabbitMQ to take advantage of things like durable topics or TTL for messages. As far as my understanding goes, using `SimpleMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend()` and `convertAndSendToUser` both end up sending the event to the browser instead of broker.

As of now, I'm trying to create a new stomp client to rabbitmq and send events through that. But I can't help feel it to be a bit hacky. Is there a way to get a hold on the stomp client used by Spring and forward my messages easily? Or am I missing something here?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took a while but turns out you don't need to get a hold of the internal stomp client (it's actually an internal TcpClient from Reactor Netty though) or anything like that. Following are the steps you need to do when you want a little bit of customization:

- Spring uses `@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker` to configure the broker or you can extend `DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration`. I ended up extending it, it makes little difference though.
- In `configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry)`, use the registry and enable stomp relay and the important part: for the registry in the same method, add `ChannelInterceptors`. You can get the stomp command and process it as required. The idea is identical to Spring Intercetpors. Add the headers needed inside that.

  final StompHeaderAccessor headerAccessor = StompHeaderAccessor.wrap(message);
  StompCommand command = headerAccessor.getCommand();

Then finally, recreate the message for sending.

```
MessageBuilder.createMessage(new byte[0], accessor.getMessageHeaders());
```

Lastly, you can test if things are actually going to RabbitMQ management console to observe if messages are actually being sent.